# C# Using Enumerable.Range()

Tags: c#, enumerable

Am I using this is the correct manner?  As far as I understand it, the following check should be false:

```
 int myVal = 37;
 if (Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Contains(myVal))
    // Do something
 else if (Enumerable.Range(11, 33).Contains(myVal))
    // Do somethiong else
```

But I seem to be getting some cases where `//Do somethiong else` is executed.  Can I not use `Enumerable.Range` is this way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The signature for [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) provides a clue:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(
    int start,
    int count
)
```

The first parameter is called *start*; the second is called ***count***. So your second call is returning 33 values starting with 11, which will include 37.

Comment: good to know, but I wonder how many people would intuitively think that!  I wish the parameters matched the IMO more obvious uses.

Comment: @Chad: OK, suppose we did it your way. How do you represent (1) an empty range, (2) a range that has as its last element Int32.MaxValue ?

Comment: @Eric: Fair enough for an empty range (how about Enumerable.Empty like String.Empty?), but couldn't you just do Enumerable.Range(0, Int32.MaxValue) to have the last element be Int32.MaxValue in the (start, end) version?

Comment: @Chad: Right; my point is that in your system, you have to *decide* which of those works, because you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: @Eric: Gotcha. Yeah, I guess since you can't have an overload you have to give it to the more versatile version. It's good to know the thinking that had to go into it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Chad: Well, actually it's not quite as simple as that. In the (start, count) system, how do you make a range that goes from -10 to Int.MaxValue ? You can't! What you really need is for the count to be a uint or a long, but that then has its own problems. It's actually a rather tricky design problem for the edge cases.

Comment: @Eric: Hmm, maybe the suggested new range syntactic sugar would be good for both cases, though now I imagine there is a problem with it?  More precisely, I wonder what the compiler would do?

IEnumerable<int> emptyRange = {};
var negTenToInf = {-10...Int32.MaxValue};

Answer (score 10):

If this particular example, its inefficient to create an enumerate in this fashion simply to check that a value lies within a particular range. `if (x < y)` is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

It will result in every value being checked, and is a little confusing, why not do:

```
int myVal = 37;
if (myVal >= 0 && myVal <= 10)
    // Do something
else if (myVal <= 33)
    // Do somethiong else
```